# add details in script properties - PS

Tags: powershell

Is there the possibility of adding attributes in the details tab of the script properties?

For example:

```
File version.
Product name.
Copyright.
Language.
Product version.
```

[image]

Comment: Those details mostly only exist for binary files known by the OS. Text based files usually do not have those details. So the answer is "No". Sorry. ;-)

Comment: It's actually [more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23372013/503046) a feature. See the answers for more links to COM structured storage and whatnot